# Map NSTableView to the "Edit" menu (ie cut/copy/past/select all)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Currently when a user is in one of the NSTableView's on my window, the Edit menu options are all greyed out. Where do I go about (for example) mapping the "Edit -> Select All" menu option to do a select all on the current NSTableView?

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Select All is enabled automatically if the focus is on the NSTableView and it allows the multiple selection.